# How to send orders and connect to a Raspberry Pi through a React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, raspberry-pi, pi4j

I have built a react app and I must connect and send orders to a Rasberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you know how to write an API server and talk to the API server using react app.

1. You can deploy your react app and an backend server on your raspberry pi.
2. You have to using a Database to store your data.

I recommend you to using SQLite as Database and Node.js to write an API server.

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/sqlite-database-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Hello thank you for your suggestion. Can i not use wifi to send my order? If my pi is connected to my local network?

Comment: Yes, it can be offline. If the website is host on same server.

Comment: Do you know any libraries that i can use to do that?

Comment: First you need to know how to write an API server and connect to SQLite. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/